# Loading CreateJS with RequrieJS “shim” dosen't work

Tags: requirejs, createjs

I have made `requirejs` work for my own modules (with `define`), but I'm not able to use `shim` for `createjs`. I've gone through countless examples and ended up using this: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/wiki/Using-easeljs-and-tweenjs-with-requirejs, but I'm getting `net::ERR_ABORTED` error

My module:

```
define(function (require) {

var createjs = require('createjs');

var start = function () {       
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
}

return {
    start: start
};

});
```

My configuration:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        easel: {
            exports: 'createjs'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        easel: 'libs/easeljs.min'
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer somewhere else; it should be:

```
require('libs/createjs');
```

**not:**

```
var createjs=require('libs/createjs');
```

As c